# Firebase Google login returns com.google.android.gms.common.api.ApiException: 12500

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-authentication

Im getting `com.google.android.gms.common.api.ApiException: 12500` and can't figure it out.
This issue is only with the google login, it works with the created accounts still.

Ive tried SHA1, SHA256, the google play service is up to date, tried different accounts, phones and emulators. Ive also updated the json file.

LoginActivity checks the email and password then checks if the server authorizes the details

```
public class LoginActivity extends AppCompatActivity{

    private EditText userName, pass;
    private FirebaseAuth mAuth;
    Dialog settingsDialog;
    private GoogleSignInClient mGoogleSignInClient;
    private SignInButton signInButton;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle bundle){
        super.onCreate(bundle);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);

        userName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.login_username_text);
        pass = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.login_password_text);
        mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

        // Configure Google Sign In
        GoogleSignInOptions gso = new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
                .requestIdToken(getString(R.string.default_web_client_id))
                .requestEmail()
                .build();

        mGoogleSignInClient = GoogleSignIn.getClient(this, gso);

        signInButton = (SignInButton) findViewById(R.id.google_signin_button);
        signInButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent signInIntent = mGoogleSignInClient.getSignInIntent();
                startActivityForResult(signInIntent, 101);
            }
        });

    }

    public void loginButtonClicked(View view){
        settingsDialog = new Dialog(this);
        if(!userName.getText().toString().isEmpty() && !pass.getText().toString().isEmpty()) {
                mAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(userName.getText().toString(), pass.getText().toString())
                        .addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                            @Override
                            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                                if (task.isSuccessful()) {

                                    // Sign in success, update UI with the signed-in user's information
                                    FirebaseUser user = mAuth.getCurrentUser();

                                    settingsDialog.getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
                                    settingsDialog.setContentView(getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.image_layout, null));
                                    settingsDialog.show();
                                    loginSucessfull(user);


                                } else {
                                    //Handle invalid password or email
                                    Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),R.string.invalid_name, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                                    toast.show();

                                }
                            }
                        });
            }
    }
    private void loginSucessfull(FirebaseUser user){
        Intent myIntent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, TopicRoomActivity.class);
        myIntent.putExtra("mauth", user);
        LoginActivity.this.startActivity(myIntent);
        finish();
    }
    public void createButtonClicked(View view){
        Intent myIntent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, CreateAccountActivity.class);
        LoginActivity.this.startActivity(myIntent);
    }

    @Override
    public void onStop(){
        super.onStop();
        if(settingsDialog != null)
            settingsDialog.dismiss();
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        // Result returned from launching the Intent from GoogleSignInApi.getSignInIntent(...);
        if (requestCode == 101) {
            Task<GoogleSignInAccount> task = GoogleSignIn.getSignedInAccountFromIntent(data);
            try {
                // Google Sign In was successful, authenticate with Firebase
                GoogleSignInAccount account = task.getResult(ApiException.class);
                firebaseAuthWithGoogle(account);
            } catch (ApiException e) {
                Log.w("*******","Google sign in failed", e);
            }
        }
    }
    private void firebaseAuthWithGoogle(GoogleSignInAccount account){

        AuthCredential credential = GoogleAuthProvider.getCredential(account.getIdToken(), null);
        mAuth.signInWithCredential(credential)
                .addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                            // Sign in success, update UI with the signed-in user's information
                            Log.w("******************","Logining in");
                            FirebaseUser user = mAuth.getCurrentUser();
                            loginSucessfull(user);
                        } else {

                        }

                        // ...
                    }
                });

    }


}
```

Exception as below :

> com.google.android.gms.common.api.ApiException: 12500: 
>           at com.google.android.gms.common.internal.ApiExceptionUtil.fromStatus(Unknown
>   Source:4)
>           at com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.GoogleSignIn.getSignedInAccountFromIntent(Unknown
>   Source:8)
>           at com.juddit.juddit_main.LoginActivity.onActivityResult(LoginActivity.java:122)
>           at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:7454)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:4353)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:4402)
>           at android.app.servertransaction.ActivityResultItem.execute(ActivityResultItem.java:49)
>           at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:108)
>           at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:68)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1808)
>           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
>           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6669)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>           at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
>           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)